Torsion in heterotic supergravity
The two-derivative Lagrangian for heterotic supergravity is
$$e^{-1}\mathcal L=e^{-2\phi}\left[R-\frac{1}{12}H^2+4(\partial\phi)^2\right],$$
where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $H$ is the three-form flux, and $\phi$ is the dilaton. Let $\Gamma$ denote the Christoffel symbols (corresponding to the unique torsion-free metric connection). If we define the torsionful connection
$$(\Gamma_+)^\rho{}_{\mu\nu}=\Gamma^\rho{}_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}H^\rho{}_{\mu\nu},$$
then the two-derivative action can be rewritten as
$$e^{-1}\mathcal L=e^{-2\phi}\left[R(\Gamma_+)+4(\partial\phi)^2\right],$$
where $R(\Gamma_+)$ is the torsionful Ricci scalar. However, the four-derivative corrections take the form
$$e^{-1}\mathcal L=e^{-2\phi}\left[R-\frac{1}{12}H^2+4(\partial\phi)^2+\frac{\alpha'}{8}(R(\tilde\Gamma_+)_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma})^2\right],$$
where
$$(\tilde\Gamma_+)^\rho{}_{\mu\nu}=\Gamma^\rho{}_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}H^\rho{}_{\mu\nu}.$$
It feels much more natural to have an action of the form
$$e^{-1}\mathcal L=e^{-2\phi}\left[R(\Gamma_+)+4(\partial\phi)^2+\frac{\alpha'}{8}\left(R(\Gamma_+)_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\right)^2\right],$$
so I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to why these two connections have different torsion? Or is it just an unfortunately inelegant fact of life?
